# Ruby on Rails email user when a new record with their preference is added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, parameters

In my Ruby on Rails application I am creating a cinema site. A user can save their favourite actor in the preferences table, and what I am trying to do is get it so that if a new film is added that has this actor, then all users with that actor as their favourite are emailed the film's details.

I have a email system already working where the user is emailed to confirm that they have successfully registered.

The problem I am having is that I need to retrieve the actors added in a new film record through the controller and if this matches the user's preference then email them. But I am struggling on how to inspect the film's params before saving it.

So far I have done the following in application controller to find user emails where they have the actor Benedict Cumberbatch as their favourite:

```
def actor_user
    actor = "Benedict Cumberbatch"
    user = Perference.where(actor: actor).pluck(:user_id)
    User.where(id: user).pluck(:email)
end
```

The problem with this as well is that the actor is hardcoded, whereas what I want to do is extract the names of the film's three actors from the film actors and inspect through these.

Films_controller:

```
def create
    @film = Film.new(film_params)
    if @film.save
        redirect_to @film
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

User_Mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'no-reply@thorcinemas.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/users/login'
    # mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

application_mailer:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  #default sender: "ben@thorcinemas.com"
  default from: "ben@thorcinemas.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :user_name            => ENV['my_email
 :password             => ENV['my_password'],
 :authentication       => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Can someone please help. I understand that I will need a new email (as at the minute I only have welcome_email.html.erb), so will need to these in due course.

This is the schema:

```
  create_table "films", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string   "title"
     t.string   "synopsis"
     t.string   "director"
     t.string   "cast1"
     t.string   "cast2"
     t.string   "cast3"
     t.date     "release_date"
     t.string   "warnings"
     t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
     t.string   "image_url"
     t.string   "certificate_id"
     t.integer  "category_id"
     t.integer  "hours"
     t.integer  "minutes"
     t.string   "video_url"
   end

   create_table "perferences", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.integer  "user_id"
     t.integer  "category_id"
     t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
     t.text     "colour"
     t.text     "actor"
   end

 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "role"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "house_no"
    t.string   "street"
    t.string   "town"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.string   "email"
    t.date     "date_of_birth"
  end
```

I understand that I have broken best practices by having actor1, actor2, actor3, in the films table rather than having an actors table, but for the purpose of this question, please ignore this.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand you correctly, after a film with some actors was added, some users should be notified by email about it.

I think [rails observers](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers) can help you. You can write your logic in `after_create`.

```
class FilmObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(film)
    # 1. fetch actors from film
    actors = [film.cast1, film.cast2, film.cast3]

    # 2. find users that should be notified
    user_ids = Perference.where(actor: actor).pluck(:user_id)
    user_emails = User.where(id: user).pluck(:email)

    # 3. send them emails
    UserMailer.send_notifications(user_emails)
  end
end
```

And in user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  # other things

  def send_notifications(emails)
    mail(to: emails, subject: 'My Shiny Notification')
  end
end
```

Of course, this code can be improved, I just want to express my idea. =)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I've read that and followed it, but do not have a clue on how to implement it

Comment: @benjs.1 I added some code to the post, maybe now my idea will be more clear =)